# Is there a way to back up and restore network domain information on an XP PC?

Tags: networking, upgrade, domain

I want to upgrade my work laptop from XP to Windows 7.  Is it possible get the network domain information of the laptop so that after a clean installation of Windows 7, I can apply it so that the laptop can be part of the network again?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to contact your system/network admin for you domain information,

- Domain name
- Computer Account

Also check that Windows 7 is approved for use on the office network and work computers.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find anything that says for certain that it does transfer the information on the domain you're transferred to, but [Windows Easy Transfer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd446674(WS.10).aspx) does provide facilities for transferring files, settings and network connections, etc from XP to Windows 7.

See also [Easy Transfer FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/Transferring-files-and-settings-frequently-asked-questions) for details of what can be transferred

Comment: Thank you but Windows Easy Transfer does not copy the machine's sid.